# Auto update svn using post-commit hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, svn-update

I am hosting a SVN repository and I want to set up a hook that launches after commit, so post-commit.
I see a lot of scripts using C but I am not sure how and if that works on Debian.

I have a Debian 32 bit server. So where would I need to set the script because I have a hooks folder with some scripts in it already (generated automatically). The current present post-commit script is this:
hooks/post-commit.tmpl

```
#!/bin/sh

# POST-COMMIT HOOK
#
# The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs
# this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.)
# named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the 
# following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed)
#
# The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so
# the program should set one explicitly if it cares.
#
# Because the commit has already completed and cannot be undone,
# the exit code of the hook program is ignored.  The hook program
# can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the
# newly-committed tree.
#
# On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'post-commit'
# invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the
# work itself too.
#
# Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will
# invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must
# have filesystem-level permission to access the repository.
#
# On a Windows system, you should name the hook program
# 'post-commit.bat' or 'post-commit.exe',
# but the basic idea is the same.
# 
# The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of
# its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the
# PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so
# that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path.
# If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the
# culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables.
# 
# Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter.
# For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in
# /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts, and in the repository at
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/


REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

"$REPOS"/hooks/mailer.py commit "$REPOS" $REV "$REPOS"/mailer.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need functionality of current script then add your script code at the end of current script. If you don't need functionality of current script then just remove current script altogether and add your own script.

EDIT: Is this script that is listed in the question the actual script that you want to be executed on post commit hook? If yes then rename it to `post-commit.sh` and copy it to `hooks` folder of your repository. Disregard `post-commit.tmpl`, because that is just an example, a template script.

Comment: The problem is, I dont have the script yet, that is what I am asking for

Comment: Hey, no this is just the tmpl I copied and pasted, I  need to know the update script as well

Comment: Why would you paste here a script that does not have any relevance to your question? And why is your question "where should I put the script" instead of "what the script should look like"? And why don't you tell us what exactly should your script do in post commit hook?

Comment: I thought I told you, I did a little research on the web and found only scripts made with C, which I think is not useful for linux/debian. Therefor I pasted this tmpl script so people would (hopefully) see it isn't C. And I was probably too fast submitting my question actual question, I'm sorry about that.
Actual question: What should the script look like to run the terminal command: "svn update /home/users/svn/" automatically after remote commits,
So if I change a file on my desktop it should be updated automatically on my server

Comment: SVN is not meant to be used in this way. Saving is one operation, commiting is another. But, you could have another process that would watch the modifications on the file and run commit if the file is changed. OTOH, if your script written in C actually does the job then just compile it and place executable file in hooks folder. SVN will handle executables just fine.

Comment: I already made it work though: creating the file: post-commit in the folder hooks with this row in it: sudo svn update /home/user/svn/ >> /home/root/logs/svn.log, this worked for me luckily :)

Comment: Good. Now that I see the script I understand what you wanted to do. I don't like automatic updates, they remind me of poor man's deploy procedure, but if it works for you then fine.

Comment: I'd like this for windows as well, how would I need to do that?

Comment: You can't do it easily. Automatic updates are not a normal thing in the world of SVN. You could do it the first time because SVN server and working copy are on the same machine, but if they are on different machines then you just can't do it. You could schedule a process in Windows that would periodically update a working copy, but I'm telling you, auto-update is not normal. What if you made a change in working copy and a collision occurs? What then?